# Multiline File in to single JSON string

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm trying to JSON encode all of the contents of a single file into a single JSON string for a curl request in BASH. The file is text so it doesn't need to be base64 encoded. The big thing is that the file is multi-lined and the line breaks matter. I'm trying to encode a PEM file.  If I strip the \n out of the file, it breaks the PEM format. I tried to see if jq would help but I don't see any option to tell it to encode newline character.

Anybody have any hints here?

Comment: MIght it be easier to manually craft the JSON in BASH or use Python or Perl?

Comment: @Ben, ...no, absolutely not easier to use bash to generate JSON -- lots of subtle caveats, and some content that's valid in JSON can't be represented in bash string variables at all (NULs, for instance -- `jq` will properly encode them as `\u0000`, whereas bash can't even read 'em except via trickery, such as representing NULs as the delimiters between elements in an array).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use jq with the -s and -R options, e.g.

```
jq -sR .           
a
b
```

Result:

```
"a\nb\n"
```

Comment: Thanks. The jq documentation for the -s option wasn't very clear to me. That's what I needed.